# TypeScript error on json import (SvelteKit)

Tags: json, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am pretty new to TypeScript and have searched quite a while now but could not find a solution specific to my problem.

In my SvelteKit application, I have a json file like that:

```json
{
  "some-key": {
    "title": "some title",
    "content": "some content"
  }
}
```

The file is being imported into a TypeScript file (`+page.ts` from SvelteKit routing) and I want to access `some-key` dynamically:

```
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';
import data from '../data.json';

export const load: PageLoad = ({ params }) => {
  if (data[params.slug]) {
    return data[params.slug];
  }
 
  throw error(404, 'Not found');
}
```

Both lines with `data[params.slug]` are yelling at me in TypeScript:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ "some-key": { title: string; content: string; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ "some-key": { title: string; content: string; }; }'.
```

I think TypeScript needs to know about the keys, somehow? Maybe the issue here is easy to fix. But I am stuck and hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by re-assigning the JSON object to a variable and type that with an interface:

```
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';
import data from '../data.json';

interface Data {
  [slug: string]: {
    title: string;
    content: string;
  };
}

const dataObject: Data = data;

export const load: PageLoad = ({ params }) => {
  if (dataObject[params.slug]) {
    return dataObject[params.slug];
  }
 
  throw error(404, 'Not found');
}
```

Please comment, if you see a better/simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be that the type of the JSON is `{ "some-key": { title: string; content: string; }; }` but you want it to be `{ [key: string]: { title: string; content: string; }; }`.

Probably what I would do is use a `.ts` file instead of JSON. That way you can also ensure that it is correctly formed and you get nicer typing annotations. Something like this:

```js
interface PageData {
    title: string,
    content: string,
}

export const data: Record<string, PageData> = {
    "some-key": {
        title: "Some title",
        content: "Some content",
    },
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sounds interesting. I have solved it by re-assigning the JSON object to a variable and type that with an interface. See my answer.